# Azure devops pipeline is not running because you have reached the maximum number of requests that can run for parallelism

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-pipelines

type 'Microsoft-Hosted Private'

Getting this error running a pipeline on a new account so there're enough credits/limits
It has been stuck for close 20+ hours now, have tried to recreate projects/subscriptions/pipelines and what not but no dice

There are similar questions on vscommunity but no answers so hoping someone has insights here

Turns out this is a "feature" implemented recently, closing this question
will leave it here till it's deleted or whatever in case someone stumbles upon this same error

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/change-in-azure-pipelines-grant-for-private-projects/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The root cause of the stuck issue is that the pipeline microsoft-hosted agent for public and private projects in the new organization has been restricted in the latest update.

For more detailed info, you could refer to these two docs: [Private Project Pipelines](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/change-in-azure-pipelines-grant-for-private-projects/), [Public Project Pipelines](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/change-in-azure-pipelines-grant-for-public-projects/).

In [Release 183](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2021/sprint-183-update#change-in-process-for-obtaining-free-pipelines-grant-in-public-projects), the reasons for adding restrictions are as follows:

> Over the past few months, the situation has gotten substantially worse, with a high percentage of new public projects in Azure DevOps being used for crypto mining and other activities we classify as abusive. In addition to taking an increasing amount of energy from the team, this puts our hosted agent pools under stress and degrades the experience of all our users – both open-source and paid.

**Private Project:**

You could send email to `azpipelines-freetier@microsoft.com` in order to get your free tier.

- Your name
- Name of the Azure DevOps organization

**Public Project:**

You could send email to `azpipelines-ossgrant@microsoft.com` in order to get your free tier.

- Your name
- Azure DevOps organization for which you are requesting the free grant
- Links to the repositories that you plan to build
- Brief description of your project

Comment: Does anyone have any experience that indicates how long it takes to be enabled after sending the email?

Comment: @FritsJ, I never got a reply but tested a few days later and it was working. So worth testing again

Comment: Now works with me, almost 4 days til it was approved.

Comment: Pipeline compute requests can be done via form at https://aka.ms/azpipelines-parallelism-request

Comment: Now works for me, mine got approved within a day after filling in the web form :-)

Comment: As @MikeWilliams pointed out, I also got approved in less than 24 hours. Woke up this morning to the confirmation in my inbox. Shout out to Microsoft!